# styling emails that come in from a php form

Tags: php, css, forms, contact-form

I have a form on a site that allows the user to enter their name, phone, email etc. When I receive this information as an email it comes in completly unformated, so it's a little harder to read. See image below:

[image: incoming email screen shot]

Is there a way I can style this using CSS, ie. make the From and email headings bold `{font-weight:bold;}`?

The php I'm using for the form is:

```
<?php
$name        = $_POST['name'];
$email       = $_POST['email'];
$phone       = $_POST['phone'];
$message     = $_POST['message'];
$formcontent ="From: $name \n Email: $email \n Phone: $phone \n Message: $message";
$recipient   = "studio@ll-i.co.uk";
$subject     = "Contact Form";
$mailheader  = "From: $email \r\n";

mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

echo "<p>Thanks for getting in touch, we'll get back to you shortly..</p>";
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to style it with inline CSS / CSS embedded in the  of a HTML file.

The $formcontent variable can contain HTML e.g.

```
"<html>
    <head>
        <title>Message</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>From:</strong> $name</p>
        <p><strong>Email:</strong> $email</p>
        <p><strong>Phone:</strong> $phone</p>
        <p><strong>Message:</strong> $message</p>
    </body>
</html>"
```

Put the CSS in the head of this like so:

```
<head>
   <style type="text/css">
       body { background-color: #ff0000; }
   </style>
</head>
```

Obviously you'll have to use these: ' instead of these " and concatenate any variables using either a full stop or comma incase you need to use speech quotes for any of the HTML.

Like this:

```
'<html>
    <head>
        <title>Message</title>
        <style type="text/css">
           body { background-color: #ff0000; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><strong>From:</strong> ',$name,'</p>
        <p><strong>Email:</strong> ',$email,'</p>
        <p><strong>Phone:</strong> ',$phone,'</p>
        <p><strong>Message:</strong> ',$message,'</p>
    </body>
</html>'
```

EDIT:

You should also change your headers like so:

```
$mailheader = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$mailheader .= "From: $email \r\n";
```

Comment: You should mention the `Content-type:` header.

Comment: Indeed I should - apologies, only done this once before and it's early for me!

Comment: No need to apologize! Just don't forget to indent your code :P

Answer (score 6):

You can format it easily enough in HTML like this - note that you can write internal CSS that will be used in the content:

```
<?php
$to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
<html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        hr {color:sienna;}
        p {margin-left:20px;}
        h3
        {
        color:red;
        text-align:left;
        font-size:8pt;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
    <h3>The fancy CSS heading!</h3>
    <p>".$email."</p>
    <hr>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        </tr>
";
// You can even do stuff like this:
for($i=0;$i<count($someArrayFromYourForm);$i++)
{
    $email.="
        <tr>
        <td>".$someArrayFromYourForm['formField']."</td>
        <td>".$someArrayFromYourForm['formField2']."</td>
        </tr>
";
}
$email.="
    </table>
</body>
</html>
";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Ah you beat me to it, some email clients don't support certain stuff so check here: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/ if something doesn't seem to work right

Comment: I see a lot of HTML emails generated without a `<head>` section. I have never been able to find a definitive explanation of if/why this is better - I suspect some ancient email client used to ignore it. But since `<style>` can legally be a child of `<body>`, I usually put my styles in the body and do away with the head. Looking at the great link that @Andy posted, it seems as though Outlook >2003 has *less* support than anything else for styling, so it's probably best to stick to those very conservative rules because Outlook >2003 will likely account for at least 50% of your readership.

Comment: @DaveRandom Interesting I will take note. I pretty much always use plaintext in emails as I try to keep it clean and simple - but that's just me :) +1